# Best practise for an admin subdomain : constantly running in the background or run after being called?

Tags: angularjs, angular-fullstack

I'm doing an angular-fullstack app and did an admin subdomain in my app.js file using

```
var subdomainOptions = {
 base: 'localhost' //base is required, you'll get an error without it.
};
app.use(require('subdomain')(subdomainOptions));

app.get('/subdomain/admin/', function(request, response) {
 response.end('hey it works');
});
```

my admin page is a full project template which am running on another localhost port.

Knowing that ultimately my app will be hosted on a server, what is best practice:

- Keep both projects (app and admin) running side by side, and linking them together
- Integrate the admin template in my app, which requires changing a LOT (!!) of things (my app is component based, the template is not)
- Another idea which i haven't thought of

Any help and info is appreciated :)

Comment: Hi William, it depends, will the admin also be using the website or are they there just to do admin features. If they use the website also (aka if it's an expenses system and you admins are HR, they'll most likely use the site as a user as well) then it's best to build the admin features and pages into the website otherwise it's fine to keep them as separate websites. Is this what you are asking?

Comment: Actually it wouldn't be a problem because both would be linked to the same database, i was just wondering if running both projects is commonly done ( its an additionnal load on the server) or if i would get hung out to dry for such a heretical practise

Comment: Even if they're pointing to the same database, it still depends on the admins usage of the system. You would not get hung out for having a website for users and a website for Admins

Comment: i don't fully grasp the limitations i would get in the case of 2 separate apps... I was thinking of the admin panel of a recap of the DB data, with the possibility of only inputting data in already preset tables. how would this be impacted?